# Class Stomper in the Walls server

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I got this class on Minecraft The Walls server called Stomper. When I tried to use it, there was nothing in my inventory. Is there a purpose of the Stomper, or is he just the guy you start out with in single command?

Comment: What mods is this server running?

Comment: I don't think it has any mods running

Comment: It must. There is nothing called "Stomper" in default Minecraft.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to assume you're talking about the Hunger Games Stomper kit. The Stomper has a special ability in that it can jump higher than other classes, and you only take a max of two hearts of fall damage. Instead, that fall damage is transferred to nearby players, allowing you to damage players by hitting the ground near them. If they are crouching at the time, the damage they take is limited to four hearts, and if they are jumping or higher than you when you hit the ground, they take no damage at all.